# Having Trouble With Post Processing Effects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, post-processing

I'm trying to write a post processing effect that alters what is eventually drawn to the screen. However, that requires getting what's currently being drawn, modifying it, and then drawing it back.

The first two steps seem to work just fine. The third step....renders all gray.

[image: Current behavior]

```
public class PostProcess : MonoBehaviour {
    void OnRenderImage(RenderTexture src, RenderTexture dest)
    {
        Texture2D proc = new Texture2D(src.width, src.height);
        proc.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, src.width, src.height), 0, 0);
        Color[] line = proc.GetPixels(src.width / 2, 0, 1, src.height);
        Debug.Log(line[0] + " : "  + line[line.Length-1]);
        proc.Apply(); //per comments
        Graphics.Blit(proc, dest);
    }
}
```

My goal is to eventually take the line pulled from the Texture2D and place it back into the texture at another point, creating a distortion.  What I'm currently getting though is useless.  I can see that the `Texture2D.ReadPixels()` call performs flawlessly as I can see that the red pixels of that UI image are visible in the texture (via the debug line) and black for the top of that column (which is correct: the camera renders a solid black background, not the skybox).  However, blitting that texture back to the screen results in useless gray nothing.

If I do `Graphics.Blit(src, dest);` instead, then it renders the scene just fine.

**Update**

After adding `proc.Apply()` the screen is no longer gray.  It is however, *heavily distorted*:

[image: Color corruption]

Scene view approximates what the camera should render, while the camera view shows what's actually rendered (again, no skybox, although turning it on makes the entire view a riot of reds and purples).

**Update 2**

I gave things a whack on a different machine running a different (older) version of Unity annd...it works.  I should have realized that it was likely a Unity bug first and foremost (this is the *third* one I've found in 5.6 and the second *this week*).

[image: All fine: look at that lovely distortion]

Comment: Try adding proc.Apply(); after ReadPixels

Comment: @JoRouss thanks for the `Apply()` call, definitely helped.

Comment: @JoRouss Hey, undelete your answer, turns out that the secondary problem is a unity bug.

Comment: Oh ok! I tryed it myself and I couldn't get it to work :O Did you find a workaround?

Comment: @JoRouss My home machine has an older version of Unity and it works fine there. When I get back to the office I'll file a bug report with Unity.  The issue doesn't invalidate your answer as I *was* missing the `.Apply()` call.

Comment: Excellent, I couldn't understand why it was not working when I tried it... Thanks for filling a bug report!

Comment: @JoRouss 5.6 has been giving me issues ever since I installed it. Two major issues with the HoloLens specifically and now this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tried it, but it looks like you forgot to `proc.Apply();` after `proc.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, src.width, src.height), 0, 0);`

```
void OnRenderImage(RenderTexture src, RenderTexture dest)
{
    Texture2D proc = new Texture2D(src.width, src.height);
    proc.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, src.width, src.height), 0, 0);
    //Do your line swapping on proc here
    proc.Apply();
    Color[] line = proc.GetPixels(src.width / 2, 0, 1, src.height);
    Debug.Log(line[0] + " : "  + line[line.Length-1]);
    Graphics.Blit(proc, dest);
}
```

ReadPixels will take the screen pixels from screen into the saved texture data.
You need to Apply() the changes after that so they are actually saved.

> Apply is a potentially expensive operation, so you'll want to change as many pixels as possible between Apply calls.

Source: [Texture2D.Apply](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.Apply.html)

I guess you should just do your line operations before Apply() and Blit()

Idealy, you should do these operations in a shader.