# Unity EncodeToPNG saving at 512x512, can't change dimension

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, io, png

I can't seem to get EncodeToPNG() to save to a file dimension other than 512 x 512 even though my texture is 1280 x 1024 which I'm pulling from the dimensions of my RenderTexture object 'tex'. What am I missing? Thank you!

```
// Saves texture as PNG file.
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;

public class SaveTexture : MonoBehaviour {

    public RenderTexture tex;
    int tWidth, tHeight;

    int getTextureWidth(int texWidth)
    {
        return tex.width;
    }

    int getTextureHeight(int texHeight)
    {
        return tex.height;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        tWidth = getTextureWidth(tex.width);
        tHeight = getTextureHeight(tex.height);

        Debug.Log("Texture Width: " + tWidth + ", Texture Height: " + tHeight);
    }

    Texture2D toTexture2D(RenderTexture rTex)
    {
        Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(tWidth, tHeight, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
        RenderTexture.active = rTex;
        tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, tWidth, tHeight), 0, 0);
        tex.Apply();
        return tex;
    }

    // Save Texture as PNG
    public void SaveTexturePNG()
    {
        Texture2D myTexture = tex.toTexture2D();

        // Encode texture into PNG
        byte[] bytes = myTexture.EncodeToPNG();
        Object.Destroy(myTexture);

        // For testing purposes, also write to a file in the project folder
        File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/../AnimalTexture/AnimalTexture.png", bytes);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious if you're using Unity 5.6, I've had an issue with reading pixels out of render textures myself (I get distorted colors and a stretched image) but I'm blit'ing the data back to the screen, not saving it. But if readpixels *was* forcing a 512x512 result that would explain *half* of my issue (the stretching).

Comment: I am using 5.6. Did you have the same problem in earlier versions of Unity?

Comment: INTERESTING. 5.4 is what I have at home and it worked fine. I already filed a bug report for the issue I had, but if this is related....HMM...

Comment: Just did a screenshot-check: my squash is precisely (the left) *half* of the screen stretched to fill, not a 512x512 region stretched-to-fill.  Still wrong, though.

Comment: Would you mind if I had a look at your method?

Comment: Sure: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44206474/having-trouble-with-post-processing-effects

Comment: have you tried changing 'src.width / 2' to just 'src.width'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145491/discussion-between-draco18s-and-greybow).

Answer (score 0):

I challenged this problem too. Actually there is no problem, file already saved with the resolution you define. On created png's inspector, there is an option named "Advanced->Non-Power of 2". It is selected "ToNearest" as default. Change it to "None" and it will be fixed.